# ¿Cómo hago efecto hover con map de imágenes?

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente mape de imágenes,podría hacerle un efecto hover,para que cuando al cruzar el mouse se les haga zoom dando un efecto de crecimiento o como podría yo hacer esto?

```html
<map name="mapa">
  <area shape="circle" coords="125,125,50" href="" />
  <area shape="rectangle" coords="325,75,425,175" href="" />
</map>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHyu.png" usemap="#mapa" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero seria crear una clase para arriba y otra clase para abajo en css y jugar con eso dependiendo si esta en hover o no.

```js
$("area").hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('arriba').siblings().toggleClass('abajo')
})
```

```css
#figuras {
  list-style: none;
}

.area1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.area2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  border-radius: 10%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.arriba {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.abajo {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map name="mapa" class="figuras">
   <area id="p_area1" class="area1"   />
   <area id="p_area2"  class="area2"   />
</map>
```

Comment: Donde añado la funcion en el mismo script o como fue,no me queda muy claro aun..

Comment: y otra cosa es que trato de hacerlo con una misma imagen y quiero saber si es posible y si es similar

Comment: @psy quieres hacer zoom para las dos figuras de una imagen? si ese es el caso creo que no se puede, yo hice algo asi pero recortando las imagenes para que se haga zoom

Comment: @psy si quieres el proyecto que hice escribeme a mi gmail porfavor

Comment: si me lo podrias facilitar seria un placer.

Answer (score 2):

Puede hacer algo como esto:

Hacer uso de `:hover` los elementos en la parte superior de la imagen (cambié los `divs` a `a-blocks`).

**Ejemplo:**

```css
.area {
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    height:475px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:320px;
}
#area2 {
    left:320px;
}
#area1:hover, #area2:hover {
    opacity:0.50;
}
```

```html
<map name="mapa">
   <area id="area1" class="area" shape="circle" coords="125,125,50" href="" />
   <area id="area2"  class="area" shape="rectangle" coords="325,75,425,175" href="" />
</map>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvHyu.png" usemap="#mapa" />
```

Comment: pero falta el zoom?

Comment: @x-rw me disculpo, estoy desde el móvil se me complica un poco poder codificar, quizás mas tarde pueda editar la pregunta y agregar el código así, o si desea puede agregarlo usted anímese a editar mi respuesta, Saludos!

Comment: Me faltaria que dicha area haga zoom con el hover

Comment: creo que debes cortar en imagenes para que se pueda hacer el zoom respectivo para cada figura, bueno esa es una manera